# Show "page=1" params in Yii CLinkPager first page link

Tags: yii

I want to make a CListView that remembers search form input. My application saves every search input (and the current page viewed by user) into user session and add the search id into the pagination params.

```
$pagination = array(
   'pageVar' => 'page',
   'currentPage' => $currentPage - 1,
   'params' => array(
         'search' => $searchId,
   )
);
```

But since the first page link at the CLinkPager don't show 'page=1' parameter, everytime I click the link from other page (say page 2), the application will think that I need the current 'search' (whose current page value is 2).

To rephrase the question, is there any way to make CLinkPager shows param 'page=1' at the first page link? Or do you have another suggestion on handling this :)

Thanks

**Edited**

My overall code is below. If you want to give a better suggestion, please do :)

```
public function actionIndex() {

            $model = new User();
            if (isset($_POST['User'])) {
                    $model->setAttributes($_POST['User']);
            } else {
                    if (isset($_GET['search'])) {
                            $searchId = $_GET['search'];
                            //Just getting a variable stored in the session
                            //array(
                            //     $searchId => array(
                            //          'model' => $model //the search model
                            //          'pageSize' => $pageSize //current pagination page size
                            //          'currentPage' => $currentPage //the search model
                            //     )
                            //);
                            $search = Yii::app()->user->getSearch($searchId); 
                            $model->setAttributes($search['model'], false);
                            $currentPage = $search['currentPage'];
                            $pageSize = $search['pageSize'];
                    } else {
                            //create default search
                    }
            }

            //Managing pageSize parameter
            if (isset($_GET['pageSize'])) { //Check whether there is pageSize in $_GET parameters
                    if (in_array($_GET['pageSize'], $this->getPageSizes())) {
                            $pageSize = $_GET['pageSize'];
                    } else {
                            $pageSize = self::DEFAULT_SEARCH_PAGESIZE;
                    }
            } else if (!isset($pageSize)) { //Check whether pageSize is already defined before
                    $pageSize = self::DEFAULT_SEARCH_PAGESIZE;
            }
            //Managing currentPage parameter
            if (isset($_GET['page'])) { //Check whether there is page parameter in $_GET parameter 
                    $currentPage = $_GET['page'];
            } else if (!isset($currentPage)) { //Check whether page is already defined before
                    $currentPage = self::DEFAULT_CURRENT_PAGE;
            }

            //Saving all into new session
            $newSearch = array(
                    'model' => $model->getAttributes(),
                    'currentPage' => $currentPage,
                    'pageSize' => $pageSize,
            );
            //Check whether if there is a search before and if it exists check whether the two search is the same
            if (!isset($search) || (serialize($search) != serialize($newSearch))) {
                    //Saves into session
                    $searchId = Yii::app()->user->saveSearch($newSearch);
            } //else use the old search id

            //-----------------------------------------------------
            //Building the search
            //Setting criteria
            $criteria = new CDbCriteria(array(
                                    'select' => array(
                                            '*', //just to simplify things
                                    ),
                            ));


            //Appending criteria to search model used
            $criteria = $model->search($criteria);

            //Appending pagination to current variables
            $pagination = array(
                    'pageSize' => $pageSize,
                    'pageVar' => 'page',
                    'currentPage' => $currentPage - 1,
                    'params' => array(
                            'search' => $searchId, //include the search ID in the link pager request URL
                    )
            );

            //Creating dataProvider for the search
            $dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('Property', array(
                                    'criteria' => $criteria,
                                    'pagination' => $pagination,
                            ));
            //Rendering
            $this->render('index', array(
                    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                    'pageSize' => $pageSize,
                    'model' => $model,
                    'searchId' => $searchId,
            ));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably extend [CPagination](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CPagination) by modifying the [createPageUrl](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CPagination#createPageUrl-detail) method and remove/change the `if($page>0)` condition to always be true. (Or better yet, add an additional parameter to turn on/off that behavior.)

Comment: I was thinking about extending CPagination. I'm looking whether there's a better way. But I'm glad there's a person who thinks the same. Thanks. :)

Comment: Without writing your own pager, I don't see how since that logic is hard-coded in the function. You could submit a feature request to modify how it works in the future.

Comment: The extension class is very simple and works quite well. :) http://pastebin.com/DJzYp6Sv