# Yii CLinkPager pagination with 2 set of paginations

Tags: php, yii, pagination

I am new to `YII` frame work

I have integrated the pagination by refer this url 
[Click here](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/25901-pagination-solution-simple-and-complex-ways/)

I used the complex way method(By refer the above url) to integrate the pagination. It is working fine. But I didn't use 2 pagination in single page. the page variables overlapped.

I need to list members and retailers separately. 2 sections are collaid with the same `page variables`.

To override the `page variable` I tried to use `pageVar` parameter. But it shows an error.

I don't know how to overwrite the page variables

```
Pagination Code for members:

        $this->widget(
    'CLinkPager', array(
        'currentPage'=>$pages->getCurrentPage(),
        'itemCount'=>$item_count,
        'pageSize'=>$page_size,
        'firstPageLabel' => '',
        'prevPageLabel' => '',
        'nextPageLabel'=>'',
        'lastPageLabel'=>'last',
        'header'=>'<p>Page :</p>',
    'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'pages'),
    ));



Pagination Code for Retailers:

        $this->widget(
    'CLinkPager', array(
        'currentPage'=>$pages_ret->getCurrentPage(),
        'itemCount'=>$item_count2,
        'pageSize'=>$page_size2,
        'firstPageLabel' => '',
        'prevPageLabel' => '',
        'nextPageLabel'=>'',
        'lastPageLabel'=>'last',
        'header'=>'<p>Page :</p>',
    'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'pages'),
    ));
```

Please give a solution. Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for a solution to pass multiple variables in the call to `render` method? If that is the case can you post the controller code?

Comment: no my passed urls is http://sitename.com/page=2
Here I want to use additional query strings while clicking the pagination link as http://sitename.com/page=2&from=mem

Or I want to override the "page=2" querystring as "page_mem=2"

Is this possible?

Comment: Have a look at this link http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/1794-add-parameters-to-clinkpager/   and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6788076/show-page-1-params-in-yii-clinkpager-first-page-link)